# Ruby system echo strange quote behavior

Tags: ruby, windows, bash

I keep my TIL diary, and daily use several Ruby and bash scripts to creating files, add contents, create aliases, and run this files as a scripts.

**upd:** this happens only at windows, more information in the bottom of this message.

**upd01:** Thanks for @glennjackman. His try discovered this behavior do no replicates on other systems.

**Super concise question**

BASH:

```
echo 'hi' # hi
```

Ruby:

```
system("echo 'hi'") # 'hi'
```

Why Ruby add quotes?

**Short question:**

BASH:

```
$ echo 'echo 20180609_Saturday/20180609.sh' > 20180609_Saturday/20180609.sh
```

20180609_Saturday/20180609.sh:

```
echo 20180609_Saturday/20180609.sh
```

Bash in Ruby:

```
system("echo 'echo #{file_path}' > #{file_path}")
```

20180609_Saturday/20180609.sh:

```
'echo 20180609_Saturday/20180609.sh'
```

Why do quotes appears in Ruby's bash request output?

**Long description:**

One of my manually routine was adding line to a newly created bash script, to test "do it fired when I call it?"

```
$ echo 'echo 20180609_Saturday/20180609.sh' > 20180609_Saturday/20180609.sh
```

and this command create add this line to the **20180609_Saturday/20180609.sh** file.

```
echo 20180609_Saturday/20180609.sh
```

I made decision to add this line in my Ruby script

```
system("echo 'echo #{file_path}' > #{file_path}")
```

and in the **20180609_Saturday/20180609.sh** I have a line with quotes:

```
'echo 20180609_Saturday/20180609.sh'
```

The same with different variants of system and backquotes:

```
# Second variand
`echo 'echo #{file_path}' > #{file_path}"`
# Third variand
system("echo \"echo #{file_path}\" > #{file_path}")
```

I still have these quotes in my newly created file. Why it's happens?

**UPD:** 
This behavior depends on platform.

Windows 8.1

```
$ ruby -e "system(\"echo 'hi'\")" ;  ruby --version
```

Output

```
'hi'
ruby 2.3.3p222 (2016-11-21 revision 56859) [x64-mingw32]
```

Ubuntu 16.04:

```
$  ruby -e "system(\"echo 'hi'\")" ;  ruby --version
```

Output:

```
hi
ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26 revision 54768) [i686-linux]
```

Comment: I'm getting `sh: /Users/myname/MyScripts/Ruby: Is a directory`, no quotes.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. What's your OS and ruby version?

Comment: @glennjackman you are right. I fire this command `ruby -e "system(\"echo 'hi'\")" ;  ruby --version` on  Ubuntu 16.04 and Windows.
In Ubuntu no quotes, in Windows there are quotes.

Comment: So the stray quotes only appear in Windows? `Kernel#system` uses the system shell. You may have `bash` or some other unix  shell available in Windows but `system` might not know that. Try setting the [RUBYSHELL](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/search?q=RUBYSHELL&unscoped_q=RUBYSHELL) environment variable to point at a unix style shell. I don't have Windows so I'm making some guesses here based on a cursory review of the docs and Ruby source.

Comment: @muistooshort I'm calling this scripts from the Gitbash. I'm not sure do it reflects on the way is Ruby working, but the scripts a executed from a *nix style shell `GNU bash, version 4.3.42(5)-release (x86_64-pc-msys)`.

Comment: Gitbash may be using bash to call your Ruby script but are you sure that Ruby is using bash when you call `system`?

Comment: @muistooshort, I'm not sure. I going to implement investigation a little bit latter. Thank you for this advise about RUBYSHELL.

Comment: See https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Kernel.html#method-i-system and https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Kernel.html#method-i-exec